# Trying to convert the values in a node to an array, clone a specific element and append the array items to that node with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<body>
    <section id="que-container">
        <div class="num" style="display: none">1000</div>
        <section id="numberContainer">
            <span class="number"></span>
        </section>

        <br class="clear">
    </section>
    <script src="components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var numbers = $('.number');
        var num = $(".num").html();
        var arr = num.split('');

        for (var i = 1; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            $('#numberContainer').append(numbers.clone());
            $('.number').append(arr[i]);
        }

        $('.number').each(function(i, val) {
            $(this).addClass('numStyle');
        })
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

I am trying to get the values inside the '.num' div, convert it to an array and append the array's items to the '#numberContainer' within spans with the 'number' class. i am not getting any errors on the console but the code doesnt seem to work. any help? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has to be like this because arrays are `0` index based:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DZJ6p/

```
var numbers = $('.number');
var num = $(".num").html();
var arr = num.split('');

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   $('#numberContainer').append(numbers.clone().append(arr[i]));
}

$('.number').each(function(i, val) {
   $(this).addClass('numStyle');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a wrong selector here

```
$('.numbers').append(arr[i]); // i didn't find any element with numbers class
```

it should be

```
 $('.number').append(arr[i]);
```

**OR**

```
  numbers.append(arr[i]);
```

**UPDATED**

your for loop starts with var i as 1... so it is missing the first index of arr i.e. arr[0], I used this in youe code..

```
$('#numberContainer').append(numbers.clone().append(arr[i]));  // u can use text(arr[i])) here
```

here is the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/zLHxV/

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure why you are using `$('#numberContainer').append(numbers.clone());`. Can you take a look at the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LBMz/) where i have put your code there.